# Passing data between view controllers inside page view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uipageviewcontroller

Sorry if this particular problem has been asked about, I followed the answers on other threads but none of them seemed to work, but I just started learning Swift so all of this is pretty new to me.

So, I have a text field in two View Controllers and I want the third View Control to display a result based on the input from the other two controllers when I press a button.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.seemuapps.com/page-view-controller-tutorial-with-page-dots) and placed the text fields, label and button like I said before. 
I placed my code (which you can see below) inside ViewControl.swift.

The problem is that when I attempt to run it I get a "Thread 1 :EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" error in the last two lines.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var a: String = ""
var b: String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var aTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let a = aTextField.text!;  
    let b = bTextField.text!;
```

I think that the error is from the data not passing between the views (because before I had everything in the same view and it worked fine), but since I only have one ViewController.swift file I couldn't figure out how to use a Segue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare same variables multiple times. Remove `let` before `a` & `b` . You have already declared `a` & `b` globally and then tried to redeclare it inside `IBAction`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var a: String = ""
var b: String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var aTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
     a = aTextField.text!;  
     b = bTextField.text!;
```

Comment: I removed let but it still gives the same error, if it helps the console says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"

Comment: did you connected the `IBOutlet` to `aTextField` &  `bTexfield` from  the storyboard?

Comment: Yes! They are both connected to ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your control outlets are setted properly.
2. In your two variables a & b are re-declared.Just update your code like below

> ```
> @IBAction func calculateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
>     self.a = aTextField.text!
>     self.b = bTextField.text!
> }
> ```

Comment: I updated it like you said, but it still gives the same error and crashes. If it helps diagnose the problem the console says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) ". I already triple-checked the outlets and they all seem to work fine. If I have all the text fields in the same View Controller as the button, the app works perfectly, but If I move them I get this error.